# Graphics clipping, why not clip pixels

Tags: graphics, clipping

I have a question about graphics clipping.
The question is: why do we need line clipping or polygon clipping?
Can we just rasterize everything then clip the pixels out of the 
clipping window?

Thanks

Comment: You probably could do that, but what makes you think it would be faster?

Comment: thanks. so it is slower?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but as people in the comments have said, it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can clip the far, left/right and top/bottom planes in screen space.

The problem is if a 3D object is **partially behind the camera**. You cannot "rasterize everything" behind a camera because typical 3D projection equations that **divide by z do not make sense behind the camera** - your points/vertices will be inverted/upside-down. If you have color/texture mapping it'll look weird. So at the very least your program will have to **clip by the near plane** and interpolate all color/texture data to the newly clipped points.

An exception is if you're doing raytracing/raycasting - rays do not go behind the camera so it works.